# iphone PC TCP/IP connection

Tags: iphone, connection, tcp

I'm looking for the faster and easy way to connect the iphone to the PC with IP/Port connection.
Anyone has a good idea?
thanks in advance
Gilad

Comment: This question is far too vague, and I'm not even sure if it's programming-related.  How do you want to communicate with the PC?  What will your application be doing?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this [Mobile Development Wiki](http://dev.im.ethz.ch/wiki/Socket_communication_on_the_iPhone) provides some information on how to communicate using low level sockets on the iPhone.